# SVG in AWS S3 content-type keep changing back to image/svg

Tags: amazon-web-services, svg, amazon-s3

After running this command code in the S3,

```
aws s3 cp --exclude "*" --include "*.svg" --content-type="image/svg+xml" --metadata-directive="REPLACE" --recursive [sourceUrl] [destUrl]
```

all the content-type is set correctly

[image: AWS S3 Metadata]

But later on, it keep changing back to `image/svg` after some time. Why does this happen? Is there any functionality in AWS that will change the content-type automatically?

Comment: Was the same file overwriten or upload again?

Comment: The same file overwritten

Comment: So after the file is overwriten the content type returns to img/svg?

Comment: After the meta data is overwritten, it will be the correct 'image/svg+xml'. But then maybe after few days, it suddenly went back to 'image/svg'